Recommended sites for good research papers on the deep history and discovery of different physics branches
I struggle with finding deep innovative resources for good research papers on the discovery and history of the development and the "hows and whys" of physics. Any suggestions, please recommend so!


MacTutor, it is mostly about math history but many theoretical physicist have an entry and it is usually sourced and insightful. : https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/
arXiv history section publishes professional essays on history of physics all the time, sometimes in very niche topics, https://arxiv.org/list/physics.hist-ph/recent
The American Institute of Physics (AIP) has a History Center. Their site includes "oral histories" which are deep interviews with famous scientists. Some of the articles are published directly on the AIP website but others are published in their blog (they also have newsletter) : https://www.aip.org/history-programs/niels-bohr-library/ex-libris-universum


Books? This is clearly the best way to go. Search for the best book on the history of [insert topic here] and then look up if the book is available to rent in archive.org


"rent in archive.org" ... or, the old-fashioned way: find it in an academic library.  The OP does not say anything about affiliation with a university.

@GeraldEdgar OP said (web)sites
